# PDF File is not downloading

Tags: php, pdf

I have the following `file.php`. My PDF is in a files folder, `file.php`, and its file are in the same directory. When I press the button, the PDF is not downloading but the `file.php` is.

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['file_name'])){
    $file= $_POST['file_name'];
    header('Content- type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachament; filename: " .$files"');
    readfile('files/'.$file);
    exit(); 
  }
?>
<form action="file.php" method="POST" >
  <input name="file_name" value="cv.pdf" type="hidden">
  <input type="submit" value="Download CV">
</form>
```

Comment: what is `$files` in `header('Content-Disposition: attachament; filename: " .$files"');` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with this if you want to download pdf using php code,set file path to `$file`

```
<?php
 $file = 'filename.pdf';
 if(!file){
     die('Error: file not found');
 }else{
     header("Cache-Control: public");
     header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
     header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
     header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
     header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
     readfile($file);
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 5):

No need of all that.
Just try this:

```
<a href="/files/yourfullPathOnTheServer.format" download>
```

You can replace a href with button :)

Comment: This kind of removes any chance of adding server side logic to it doesn't like checking for authorisation.

Comment: In that case, You can submit via POST and get the full path in the reponse. And use window redirect in javascript to open the file in another window :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to just change the below code

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachament; filename: " .$files"');
```

with this:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachament; filename: '$files'");
```

Also remember that

> It is important to notice that header() must be called before any actual output is sent (In PHP 4 and later, you can use output buffering to solve this problem)

Comment: It's look like here is a space in your `content-type ` , `header('Content- type: application/pdf');`. Remove space and try again.